# How can 'twice' be an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

> I’m **twice** your age. [(Oxford Dictionaries)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/twice)

It looks like ‘twice’ is a preposition to me, yet it’s an adverb. On what procedure do you think in your brain, can this be an adverb?

Comment: Taking into account [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/2979/126) *(**twice** is called an adverb in dictionaries because "adverb" is the traditional wastebasket category)* to the more "generic" problem of categorisation, I think the current question is Not Constructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an argument that it is an adverb:

In the sentence "I am your age", the word "am" expresses a relationship between the subject "I" and the phrase "your age".  If I insert the word "twice", it modifies "am", changing the relationship between them.  I don't think this works particularly well; I feel like "twice" modifies the following phrase, instead.  If I say "I am twice", I ask, "Twice *what*?"  It feels incomplete.

I think it makes more sense to analyze it another way.  I would say "age" is a noun modified by the [*determiner*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/determiner) "your" to form the phrase "your age"; this in turn is modified by the [*predeterminer*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/predeterminer) "twice" to form the phrase "twice your age".  This phrase is linked to the subject "I" by the verb "am".

Comment: Can you use _twice your age_ as subject of a sentence? _All your friends_ can be the subject of a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

In context, "twice" means "two times".  Ex:

> I'm twice your age!  I'm 40, I don't have much in common with twenty-year-olds.

Note it doesn't always mean *exactly* two times, but an approximation.  If a parent were upset about their child dating someone older, for example, they would say "He/she's twice your age!" if the other person were somewhere in the range of two times the child's age.

Comment: The question is if _twice_ is an adverb in the example sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Since *twice* modifies *am* (a verb), *twice* is an adverb.
You could say "I am your age"; adding *twice* you are altering the meaning of *am*.

Comment: I think it modifies the prasal adjective "your age". Given that "I am" is a copula construction, "I am your age" makes "your age" into an adjective. Just like "I am red". In "I am very red" *very* is an adverb modifying an adjective.

Comment: What follows a linking verb is a subject complement; I would not call it an adjective. In "Alice is a child" _a child_ doesn't seem an adjective.