# Is there a more restrictive criterion to distinguish a preposition from an adverb

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

The definition normally given for *adverb* is similar to the following one:

> a word or phrase that modifies or qualifies an adjective, verb, or other adverb or a word-group

*Preposition* is normally described using the following words:

> a word governing, and usually preceding, a noun or pronoun and expressing a relation to another word or element in the clause

The NOAD, for which *twice* is only an adverb, uses the following examples for *twice*:

> She had been married twice.
>   The tablets should be taken twice a day.
>   I'm twice your age.
>   an engine twice as big as the original

The same dictionary reports the following examples of prepositions:

> the man **on** the platform
>   she arrived **after** dinner
>   What did you do it **for**

Looking at the examples, "she arrived after dinner" seems similar to "I am twice your age"; using the definition of *preposition*, I could say that twice express a relation between *I* and *your age*, in the same way *after* expresses a relation between *she* and *dinner*.
*The man on the platform* seem similar to *the man twice your age*; if *on* is a preposition on the first phrase, *twice* should be a preposition in the second one.

Giving the definitions for *preposition*, and *adverb*, it seems I could use classify a word as adverb, or preposition.

Are there more restrictive criteria, to distinguish a preposition from an adverb? Is the relation between two words used to be define *preposition* restricted to a specific set of relations? For example, *on* in *the man on the platform* is a preposition because the relation between *man* and *platform* is a specific one.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/how-can-twice-be-an-adverb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As retired Professor of Linguistics [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) says [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/101078/2637):

> **twice** is *called an adverb in dictionaries because "adverb" is the traditional wastebasket category*.

From [this Wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Number_words) on "number words":

> In some grammars, number words get assigned a dedicated part of speech, called "number" or "numeral". This part of speech can subsume cardinal numbers and ordinal numbers, and some other classes of number words.
>    These other words would in English include "double" (adjective), "triple" (adjective), "doubly", "triply", "twice", "thrice".

---

I've no reason to disagree with [this Yahoo Answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081015042950AAtcdCD) to *What part of speech is the word **after**?*:

*preposition*
behind in place or position; following behind: *men lining up one after the other.*

*adverb*
behind; in the rear: *Jill came tumbling after.*

*adjective*
later in time; next; subsequent; succeeding: *In after years we never heard from him.*

*conjunction*
subsequent to the time that: *after the boys left.*

---

Consider also [my own question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/what-exactly-is-an-adverb) asking *What exactly is an “adverb”?*, where the answers basically net down to the fact that a word is an adverb only *when and if it's used adverbially*. Any given word isn't necessarily an adverb *all the time*; the categorisation attaches to the *usage*, not the *word itself*.

I think what all this amounts to is you reach a certain point in classification of "parts of speech" where the process is no longer helpful. Such terminology is a "post-hoc" attempt to describe how we actually use language, but it's an imperfect descriptive framework.

It's therefore my opinion that in a case like this, OP's attempt to narrow down the description so he can unambiguously classify specific "awkward" words as one thing or another is really a lost cause anyway.

Comment: Exactly. Short form: *Parts of speech* do not categorize words but **uses** of words.

Comment: @StoneyB: That's one half of the answer. The other half is that even in a specific usage, sometimes the available categories aren't sufficiently clear-cut to always admit of a definitive answer to the question *"What part of speech is **this** word in **this** context?"*

Comment: Yah. As Dr John keeps telling us, what matters is what it does, not what you name it.

Comment: There are different words for what a word is and what a word does. *Usually* is an adverb, but it performs the role of an adverbial in the clause _I usually get up later on Sundays._

Comment: @Barrie: I'm not aware of that as a formal distinction. Wouldn't that imply ***a** prepositional, **an** adjectival,* and ***a** conjunctional* should be used to describe such terms *when performing roles?* (Google spellchecker isn't at all happy with the last of those! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Not really. English clauses contain two or more of the components Subject, Verb, Object, Adverbial, Complement and they can be arranged in seven different combinations.

Comment: @Barrie: Ah, right. That's the nomenclature whereby adjective & adverb are both just called *adverbial* elements, yes?

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Oh no. An adjective can be part of the Subject, part of the Object, part or all of the Complement, or part of the Adverbial. An adjective can't itself, at least in Standard English, be an Adverbial. Things like Subjects and Adverbials are functions. Things like nouns and adjectives are categories.

Comment: @Barrie: oic. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial) page for adverbials warns about lack of citations. But if I could trouble you to glance at [this page](http://babelnet.sbg.ac.at/themepark/grammar/clauseelements.htm), can I reasonably bookmark it as my "quick reference" for all these terms?

Comment: I am irresistibly reminded of the debate between Homoousians and Homoiousians.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, per the broad thrust of my answer, I'm not too concerned with the actual classification of any specific "awkward" examples. But obviously such terminology is useful for painting the broader picture, and I *am* interested when Barrie says *Subjects and Adverbials are **functions*** - this sounds potentially a better descriptive framework for understanding sentence structure than what I'm used to (in my extremely limited fashion! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's the terminology of Functional Grammar which has been adopted (or adapted) by many neo-traditional grammarians alongside the old POS terminology (but POS itself is now called *word class*). Be sure to observe the subtle distinction between *adverbial* and *Adverbial*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Yes, that page seems to be on the right lines. Huddleston and Pullum illustrate the difference between function and category by considering the sentence _Some people complained about it._  They say ‘Function is a relational concept: when we say that _some people_ is subject we are describing the relation between it and _complained_, or between it and the whole clause . . . A category, by contrast, is a class of expressions which are grammatically alike.’ ('A Student's Introduction to English Grammar', p. 14)

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Subject, Verb, Object, Complement and Adverbial come from the traditional approach to grammar. Functional grammar sees a clause as being centred on various kinds of Process. The elements of a clause indicating what is involved in the Process are different kinds of Participant. Any element of a clause that adds information about the situation surrounding the Process is a Circumstance. It’s an approach that relates language to its purpose. As such it offers insights to communication that purely structural grammar cannot.

Comment: See [*Fusion of functions: the syntax of once, twice and thrice*](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=1379900) (Payne, Huddleston, and Pullum, 2007).

Answer (score 0):

One way that I distinguish an adverb from a preposition, is the removing test; you can remove an adverb, and the sentence would still make sense, but not a preposition.

Adverb: We went out last night (We went last night).

Preposition: We went out the door (We went the door).